# How do I solve for a variable in a standard normal distribution using R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I'm trying to solve this expression using R and I have no clue.

```
P(Z >= c) = 0.025
```

I found `P(Z < c) = 0.975` using the complement rule but do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: `... = P(Z <= c)` which is the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)...does `[qnorm](0.975)` give you what you need using the inverse of the CDF? See also [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-January/017624.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), think about the inverse.
[image: Derivation of the inverse cumulative distribution function]

Here, `p = 0.975`.

Fortunately, other people have already built functions like these.  Compare the definition of the inverse CDF to the quantile function for insights into why the letter *q* is used by some packages.

I'll leave the rest up to you.